# February 2017 golf

Tags: lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

How many minutes are there in February 2017?

This is "puzzling golf".  The shortest correct answer wins.

PS: The puzzle is not so much to compute the result, but rather to express it in fewer than 5 digits.

Comment: Please do not use tags that don't exist unless you're *really* sure that they need to be created.

Comment: Sorry.  The tags were accepted by SE so I thought they existed.

Comment: To downvoters: don't forget to revise your vote when you have seen the answer.

Comment: @FlorianF [Once you hit 300 rep you can create tags](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As pointed out, there are

> 28 days x 24 hours x 60 minutes = 40,320 minutes in February 2017.

This can be expressed as:

> (4x7) days x (3x8) hours x (1x2x5x6) minutes = 8! minutes.

Comment: Correct!  And I decided to accept this answer because it is more explicit.

Answer (score 17):

I can do it in just 2 symbols (excluding the word minutes):

> 8! minutes

Comment: Yess!  This is the inteded answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

The shortest answer I can think of:

> 0

Because

> The word "minutes" does not appear in "February 2017"

---

But if you're looking to express the actual duration of the month in minutes, 40320, how about this:

> 10

using

> base 40320.

Comment: 1st answer: No. Some calculation is required to solve the puzzle.  2nd: giving the base would be part of the answer.

Comment: Then how is this lateral thinking and not formation of numbers?

Comment: I think you are right.  It is not lateral thinking any more after I explained the puzzle in in the way to express the answer.

Comment: If only there were enough unicode characters to express it in base 40321

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile: Aren’t there? (Or was that the point?)

Answer (score 4):

The Prime Factors :

> $2^7\times 3^2\times 5\times 7$
>  (without the exponents it's 4 numbers)

Or HEXA powa :)

> 9D80

Comment: Because it's the first four primes: $7$,$2$,$1$,$1$ (just the exponents).

Comment: well, 1 is not a prime...

Comment: I was listing the exponents for the first four primes. 2^7, 3^2, 5^1, 7^1.

Comment: Ok I didn't understand what you were asking, if the question is why the first 4 primes, here is The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic :
Every positive integer greater than one can be written uniquely as a product of primes, with the prime factors in the product written in order of nondecreasing size.

Comment: You said "without the exponents it's 4 numbers", but discarding the first 4 primes would lose less information (if you know it's exponents, exponents for primes is a reasonable deduction).

Comment: Gotcha eventually :D